Why does my cylinder create 4 horns when I only want 2 while beveling the top?
I am working on a model where I want to create a human hat with two horn-like shapes. I started with a cylinder and used Proportional Editing to modify the top and bottom of the cylinder. However, when I try to bevel the top part to create two cones for the horns, I end up getting 4 horns instead of the intended 2.
This is before bevel:

After bevel i get this:

I want it to look like this:


Hello how did you create the 2 horns?

I didn’t create the horns,that is from a tutorial

i think you can just select the vertices,which formed the horns and just move them down using G.This way you have only 2 horns


select the vertex in edit mode, go to vertex data , check the bevel weight, make it zero , if its mot working , try , press "A" change the bevel weight to zero in vertex data , i hope this works
